# tika.parseToString returns empty string

Tags: java, maven, apache-tika

Why the following application won't print the file contents?

```
package org.example;

import org.apache.tika.Tika;
import java.io.File;

public class TikaFirstTry {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Tika tika = new Tika();

        for (String fileName : args){
            System.out.println(fileName);
            String text = tika.parseToString(new File(fileName));
            System.out.println("text is: " + text);
        }
    }
}
```

The file **foo.txt** contains:

```
pizzaaaaa
```

The program output is:

```
C:/Users/me/Desktop/foo.txt
text is:
```

and no exception is thrown...

my pom contains

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
    <artifactId>tika-async-cli</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you are using a SNAPSHOT version? Why not using the release version 2.7.0... ?

Comment: What happens if you use the more normal `tika-parsers` dependency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

These are the relevant `dependency` sections in `pom.xml` which are required to run your example:

```xml
<project>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-async-cli</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-parsers-standard-package</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Full answer

First of all, as @khmarbaise has noticed, your `tika-async-cli` dependency version looks faulty. As of 26 February, there are only 2 versions of artifact [`tika-async-cli`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tika/tika-async-cli) available for download: `2.6.0` and `2.7.0`. The one you've shared is not on the list and `mvn install` throws an error when trying to fetch that version from Maven Central.

You need both `tika-core` and `tika-parsers-*` dependencies to run your example.

You've already included `tika-core` since `tika-async-cli` includes it as a direct dependency:

```bash
$ mvn dependency:tree
# ...
[INFO] +- org.apache.tika:tika-async-cli:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tika:tika-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.19.0:compile       
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:compile     
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:jar:2.19.0:compile
# ...
```

As @Gagravarr has hinted, one of the `tika-parsers-*` was missing in your `dependencies` section. Currently these come as 3 separate dependencies:

- `tika-parsers-standard-package`,
- `tika-parser-scientific-module`,
- `tika-parser-sqlite3-module`.

As I understand, this came about with Tika 2.0 (more on that [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Migrating+to+Tika+2.0.0)). For your purposes, `tika-parsers-standard-package` seems sufficient.

The https://github.com/apache/tika README somewhat proposes the [Maven Configuration](https://github.com/apache/tika#maven-dependencies) but it is unfortunately incomplete.

I *suspect* you do not see an exception because Tika falls back to an [`EmptyParser`](https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/2.7.0/tika-core/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/parser/EmptyParser.java) when parsers are not loaded. It creates an empty XHTML document in the background and such a document has no text content. Hence your code outputs an empty string.